# Data takes too much time to load in the list

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am facing a problemm when i try to populate a `RecyclerView` with data from `SQLite Database`. The thing is that i get the data correctly but they do not show up in the `RecyclerView`.

My code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_times);
        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_list);
        databaseAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(TimesActivity.this);
        checkOrientation();
        new FetchDataTask().execute();
    }

    private class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<ValueList>>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(TimesActivity.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading data...");
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ValueList> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                databaseAdapter.open();
                for (int position = 0; position<= databaseAdapter.getData().size(); position++){
                     String name = databaseAdapter.getData().get(position).getName();
                     String value = databaseAdapter.getData().get(position).getValue();
                     String date = databaseAdapter.getData().get(position).getDate();
                     String day = databaseAdapter.getData().get(position).getDay();
                     itemsList.add(new ValueList(name, value, date, day));
                }
                databaseAdapter.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return itemsList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<ValueList> valueLists) {
            super.onPostExecute(valueLists);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            listAdapter = new TimesAdapter(TimesActivity.this, valueLists);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    }
```

and my database `Adapter` class

```
public List<String> getName(){
        db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        if (cursor != null ) {
            if  (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String day = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
                    names.add(day);
                }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        db.close();
        return names;
    }
```

The timesAdapter class:

```
public class TimesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TimesAdapter.TimesViewHolder>{

    Context context;
    List<ValueList> items;

    public TimesAdapter(Context context, List<ValueList> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public TimesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
        TimesViewHolder holder = new TimesViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TimesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(items.get(position).getName());
        holder.value.setText(items.get(position).getValue());
        holder.day.setText(items.get(position).getDay());
        holder.date.setText(items.get(position).getDate());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public class TimesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView name, value, day, date;

        public TimesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_column);
            value = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.value_column);
            day = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.day_column);
            date = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_column);
        }

    }
}
```

and the ValueList class:

```
public class ValueList {
    private String name, value, date, day;

    public ValueList(String name, String value, String date, String day) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.date = date;
        this.day = day;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }
}
```

Any ideas? The dialog never dismiss and the data are not showing.

Comment: So... you're making 8 queries for each single row and then complain that it's slow?

Comment: Why is it 4 queries for each row?

Comment: No, 8. 4 in the `for` condition and 4 in the `for` body: `getName()` runs a query. `getDate()` runs a query. `getValue()` runs a query. `getDay()` runs a query.

Comment: So what do you suggest?

Comment: **1** - Precalculate the values for the `for` condition BEFORE the `for` loop, so that they only get executed once, and not at each `for` iteration. **2** - get the 4 values with a single query, instead of making a query for each single column.

Comment: Can you give me an exampe with code?

Comment: Come on... you're an experienced user. 888 rep should mean something. You already have your `rawQuery()` set to retrieve all the columns. Just return all the 4 values you need.

Comment: Yes i meant what do you mean precalculate

Comment: Simply retrieve the fields you need (assign them to 4 variables), like in the query you will execute inside the loop - nothing different.

Comment: Even better, re-reading your code... simply return a cursor ONCE. and then loop through its results. This would be a real rocket-boost.

Comment: You're querying all of your columns, but you're only adding `name` to the list, add all of the columns so `name`, `values`, `dattes`, `days`

Comment: oh. i have 4 methods like getName(). one for each thing i want to put in the list.

Comment: Which is what slows you down. (and also re-executing them at each for iteration doesn't help).

Comment: but why do you have 4 other methods, when you're querying everything in `getName()`, add them all to a list and then call them each by calling `yourList.getValue()` where `getValue()` is the data you want to retrieve this way you can optimize your for loop as well to `for (int i = 0; i < yourList.size(); i++)` then query through your list which already has all the data in it

Comment: You shouldn't call `databaseAdapter.getData()` in your `TimesAdapter` constructor because you can't guarantee it'll finish processing the information before you call `setAdapter` thus showing you nothing Can you post the code for `ValueList` and `TimesAdapter`?

Comment: check the editted question please

Comment: Now you are running a query on each for iteration (to get the size), plus 4 queries per each row.

Comment: Give me an example with code please

Comment: i think the problemm is that i am using recyclerview instead of listview and simplecursor adapter